# Windows: Separating input from 2 Mice

Tags: c#, windows, io

Initially, I want to use 2 mice for an application with separate pointers and interaction between the 2 mice(e.g. selecting a rectangular area). Later I might want to have a second pointer available generally in windows. I thought this might be possible by simulating a stylus pen with the second mouse.

My main question though is: Am I right to use a system hook as opposed to RawInput, DirectInput or InputX?

If using a system hook I presume I need to use WH_MOUSE_LL rather than WH_MOUSE even if the application is running on one thread? My preferred language is C#, but again I presume that using DLL imports means I can do anything that's possible in C++ or C.

Comment: How about using microsoft multipoint sdk ? http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/

Comment: I'm having another look at it. However there are limitations like no extended desktop, so I think I'd prefer to develop my own interface.

Comment: Hardware wise, it could be done by mimicking a joypad (in mouse form) with one analog axis that represents the change in X/Y per update, with 3/4 buttons for clicking.

Comment: I have used the Multipoint SDK. The limitations started to get annoying for me too! If you have the time, I'd recommend you look into alternatives (and publish your results!). If I recall correctly, you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for through the RawInput interfaces. I don't believe a system hook is necessay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using system hook is the way to go in WINDOWS. You can use C# with InteropServices and the apropriate COM+ objects, altough creating a C++ class and wrapping it would be a better approach. I've done it myself with keyboard events. I could LOG all keyboards typing... And yes, you have to use WH_MOUSE_LL.